# Linking image's to Mouseevents in java

Tags: java, netbeans, mouseevent, mouselistener

Some background I am developing a game in java, I am using Netbeans to build it I currently have 2  java files

App.java

Board.java

Right Now I can create and display a simple chess board with all the pieces in the right positions the problem I am having is assigning any mouseevents to those chess pieces

Currently i wrote test code using textpad and no folder links for the images and have been able to get the mouse events to work there so I know there is no problem in the code for the events.

But Now that I am writing the program cleaner in Netbeans the mousevents don't work any more

So I am ammusing I am not linking them correctly to the new chess board and the new peieces

Here is the chess Board In netbeans (Not working version)

```
package chessgame;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE;

public class Board extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

    JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    JPanel chessBoard;
    JLabel chessPiece;
    int xAdjustment;
    int yAdjustment;
    int startX;
    int startY;
    int initialX;
    int initialY;
    JPanel panels;
    JLabel pieces;

    public Board() {
        Dimension boardSize = new Dimension(600, 600);

        //  This is a Layered Pane for this application
        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        getContentPane().add(layeredPane);
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(boardSize);

        //Add a chess board to the Layered Pane
        chessBoard = new JPanel();
        layeredPane.add(chessBoard, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        chessBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
        chessBoard.setPreferredSize(boardSize);
        chessBoard.setBounds(0, 0, boardSize.width, boardSize.height);

        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            JPanel square = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            chessBoard.add(square);

            int row = (i / 8) % 2;
            if (row == 0) {
                square.setBackground(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : Color.gray);
            } else {
                square.setBackground(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.gray : Color.white);
            }
        }
        // Setting up the Initial Chess board.
        //White Side
        for (int i = 8; i < 16; i++) {
            pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhitePawn.png")));
            panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(i);
            panels.add(pieces);
        }
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhiteRook.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(0);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhiteKnight.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(1);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhiteKnight.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(6);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhiteBishup.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(2);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhiteBishup.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(5);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhiteKing.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(3);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhiteQueen.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(4);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/WhiteRook.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(7);
        panels.add(pieces);

        //Black Side
        for (int i = 48; i < 56; i++) {
            pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/BlackPawn.png")));
            panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(i);
            panels.add(pieces);
        }
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/BlackRook.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(56);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/BlackKnight.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(57);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/BlackKnight.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(62);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/BlackBishup.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(58);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/BlackBishup.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(61);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/BlackKing.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(59);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/BlackQueen.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(60);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chessgame/PieceImages/BlackRook.png")));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(63);
        panels.add(pieces);
    }

    //Mouse Events For All Piece Interactions 

    //This method checks if there is a piece present on a particular square.
    private Boolean piecePresent(int x, int y) {
        Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(x, y);
        if (c instanceof JPanel) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //This is a method to check if a piece is a Black piece.
    private Boolean checkWhiteOponent(int newX, int newY) {
        Boolean oponent;
        Component c1 = chessBoard.findComponentAt(newX, newY);
        JLabel awaitingPiece = (JLabel) c1;
        String tmp1 = awaitingPiece.getIcon().toString();
        if (((tmp1.contains("Black")))) {
            oponent = true;
        } else {
            oponent = false;
        }
        return oponent;
    }

    /*
     This method is called when we press the Mouse. So we need to find out what piece we have
     selected. We may also not have selected a piece!
     */
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        chessPiece = null;
        Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (c instanceof JPanel) {
            return;
        }

        Point parentLocation = c.getParent().getLocation();
        xAdjustment = parentLocation.x - e.getX();
        yAdjustment = parentLocation.y - e.getY();
        chessPiece = (JLabel) c;
        initialX = e.getX();
        initialY = e.getY();
        startX = (e.getX() / 75);
        startY = (e.getY() / 75);
        chessPiece.setLocation(e.getX() + xAdjustment, e.getY() + yAdjustment);
        chessPiece.setSize(chessPiece.getWidth(), chessPiece.getHeight());
        layeredPane.add(chessPiece, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        if (chessPiece == null) {
            return;
        }
        chessPiece.setLocation(me.getX() + xAdjustment, me.getY() + yAdjustment);
    }

    /*
     This method is used when the Mouse is released...we need to make sure the move was valid before
     putting the piece back on the board.
     */
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```

And here is the test code I wrote in textpad (Working Mousevents version)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ChessProject extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    JPanel chessBoard;
    JLabel chessPiece;
    int xAdjustment;
    int yAdjustment;
    int startX;
    int startY;
    int initialX;
    int initialY;
    JPanel panels;
    JLabel pieces;


    public ChessProject(){
        Dimension boardSize = new Dimension(600, 600);

        //  Use a Layered Pane for this application
        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        getContentPane().add(layeredPane);
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(boardSize);
        layeredPane.addMouseListener(this);
        layeredPane.addMouseMotionListener(this);

        //Add a chess board to the Layered Pane
        chessBoard = new JPanel();
        layeredPane.add(chessBoard, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        chessBoard.setLayout( new GridLayout(8, 8) );
        chessBoard.setPreferredSize( boardSize );
        chessBoard.setBounds(0, 0, boardSize.width, boardSize.height);

        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            JPanel square = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
            chessBoard.add( square );

            int row = (i / 8) % 2;
            if (row == 0)
                square.setBackground( i % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : Color.gray );
            else
                square.setBackground( i % 2 == 0 ? Color.gray : Color.white );
        }

        // Setting up the Initial Chess board.
        for(int i=8;i < 16; i++){
            pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhitePawn.png") );
            panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(i);
            panels.add(pieces);
        }
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhiteRook.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(0);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhiteKnight.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(1);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhiteKnight.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(6);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhiteBishup.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(2);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhiteBishup.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(5);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhiteKing.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(3);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhiteQueen.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(4);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("WhiteRook.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(7);
        panels.add(pieces);
        for(int i=48;i < 56; i++){
            pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("BlackPawn.png") );
            panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(i);
            panels.add(pieces);
        }
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("BlackRook.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(56);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("BlackKnight.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(57);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("BlackKnight.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(62);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("BlackBishup.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(58);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("BlackBishup.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(61);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("BlackKing.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(59);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("BlackQueen.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(60);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("BlackRook.png") );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(63);
        panels.add(pieces);
    }

    /*
        This method checks if there is a piece present on a particular square.
    */
    private Boolean piecePresent(int x, int y){
        Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(x, y);
        if(c instanceof JPanel){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    /*
        This is a method to check if a piece is a Black piece.
    */
    private Boolean checkWhiteOponent(int newX, int newY){
        Boolean oponent;
        Component c1 = chessBoard.findComponentAt(newX, newY);
        JLabel awaitingPiece = (JLabel)c1;
        String tmp1 = awaitingPiece.getIcon().toString();
        if(((tmp1.contains("Black")))){
            oponent = true;
        }
        else{
            oponent = false;
        }
        return oponent;
    }

    /*
        This method is called when we press the Mouse. So we need to find out what piece we have
        selected. We may also not have selected a piece!
    */
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        chessPiece = null;
        Component c =  chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (c instanceof JPanel)
            return;

        Point parentLocation = c.getParent().getLocation();
        xAdjustment = parentLocation.x - e.getX();
        yAdjustment = parentLocation.y - e.getY();
        chessPiece = (JLabel)c;
        initialX = e.getX();
        initialY = e.getY();
        startX = (e.getX()/75);
        startY = (e.getY()/75);
        chessPiece.setLocation(e.getX() + xAdjustment, e.getY() + yAdjustment);
        chessPiece.setSize(chessPiece.getWidth(), chessPiece.getHeight());
        layeredPane.add(chessPiece, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        if (chessPiece == null) return;
         chessPiece.setLocation(me.getX() + xAdjustment, me.getY() + yAdjustment);
     }

    /*
        This method is used when the Mouse is released...we need to make sure the move was valid before
        putting the piece back on the board.
    */
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
   }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){

    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    /*
        Main method that gets the ball moving.
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new ChessProject();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
     }
}
```

Currently the only thing the mosueevents are set up to do is allow the user to drag any piece they want anywhere on the board

Hopefully someone can see where I am going wrong with the linking of the events

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in your `ChessProject` you did...

```
layeredPane.addMouseListener(this);
layeredPane.addMouseMotionListener(this);
```

But in your `Board` project, you've made no such calls.  Remember, if you want to be told about mouse events, you must register a listener for them

Comment: It's always the small things ;)

Comment: yeah always the small thing's if u have the chance maybe u can have a look at this question aswell I say I have problay messed up a link or forgotten something again, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893717/images-just-disappear-when-moved-using-mouse-events-in-java