# Disappearing Problems Using a Released MouseEvent In Java

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouselistener

Currently I have a game that I am building in Netbeans, and have been able to create a board, place the pieces and allow them to be moved anywhere using mouseveent's

But now I have ran into a problem when trying to code the pieces on the board to only do allowed actions.

The problem I am having is that every piece is still allowed to be moved but now when it is moved the selected piece disappears from the board completely ingorning all the new function in the mouse release event

**The code I am trying to add is for the WhitePawn which is the only piece that should be allowed to move right now**

The rest if they are tried to move should just return to there set positions regardless of where they are dragged. I have removed all code not relevant to the question and ran the debugger. From that I know a fact that the problem is somewhere in the mouse release event code, I just cant find it.

```
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (chessPiece == null) {
            return;
        }

        chessPiece.setVisible(false);
        Boolean success = false;
        Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
        String tmp = chessPiece.getIcon().toString();
        String pieceName = tmp.substring(0, (tmp.length() - 4));
        Boolean validMove = false;

//Pawn Moves
//White Pawn
        if (pieceName.equals("WhitePawn")) {
            if (startY == 1) {
                if ((startX == (e.getX() / 75)) && ((((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 1) || ((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 2)) {
                    if ((((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 2)) {
                        if ((!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) && (!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY() + 75)))) {
                            validMove = true;
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ((!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY())))) {
                            validMove = true;
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            } else {
                int newY = e.getY() / 75;
                int newX = e.getX() / 75;
                if ((startX - 1 >= 0) || (startX + 1 <= 7)) {
                    if ((piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) && ((((newX == (startX + 1) && (startX + 1 <= 7))) || ((newX == (startX - 1)) && (startX - 1 >= 0))))) {
                        if (checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                            validMove = true;
                            if (startY == 6) {
                                success = true;
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                            if ((startX == (e.getX() / 75)) && ((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 1) {
                                if (startY == 6) {
                                    success = true;
                                }
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!validMove) {
            int location = 0;
            if (startY == 0) {
                location = startX;
            } else {
                location = (startY * 8) + startX;
            }
            String pieceLocation = pieceName + ".png";
            pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(pieceLocation)));
            panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(location);
            panels.add(pieces);
        } else {
            if (success) {
                int location = 56 + (e.getX() / 75);
                if (c instanceof JLabel) {
                    Container parent = c.getParent();
                    parent.remove(0);
                    pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("WhiteQueen.png")));
                    parent = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(location);
                    parent.add(pieces);
                } else {
                    Container parent = (Container) c;
                    pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("WhiteQueen.png")));
                    parent = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(location);
                    parent.add(pieces);
                }
            } else {
                if (c instanceof JLabel) {
                    Container parent = c.getParent();
                    parent.remove(0);
                    parent.add(chessPiece);
                } else {
                    Container parent = (Container) c;
                    parent.add(chessPiece);
                }
                chessPiece.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

*Image showing the folder layout of My build in case I have you can see somewhere that is not linked probably*

[image: Folder Layout]

Hopefully someone can see where I am going wrong, as I just want to get one piece moving before I split the pieces away from the board.java file completely into a new java file

Comment: The key to a solution, either by you or by us is to simplify and isolate the problem first. Consider creating and posting a [minimal working example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), one that we can compile and run unaltered, and that demonstrates your problem. This way you will be required to identify exactly what code is relevant to the problem, and we can understand the problem without having to go through a literal ton of unrelated code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the problem has to be from the movement of the pawn down as the code all works fine up to that point than the problem kicks in

Comment: Note that your MCVE would not require images on disk that we don't have available to us.

Comment: Jamie, I'm at work and can look at a reasonable amount of code, but this is too much. Maybe someone else has the times, but please do keep in mind that we're volunteers with time limits, with work with lives.

Comment: Please check the [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) link for the details as the program you create and post should be small, should compile, and should run for us. Often the effort of creating one of these tools (and it does take a bit of effort) is worth it, as often you see the problem yourself in the process of creation, and can then solve the problem yourself. Failing that, you'll give us an amazingly small and functional program that we'll be able to understand well and to experience your problem first hand.

Comment: Please note update to answer from yesterday. I think I see the possible cause of your problem, but it will require you debugging with your running code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels what update answer from yesterday has not been edited for over 19 hours ?

Comment: The information that I placed below the separating line was added in a second edit. Have you tried the debug recommendation yet? Have you gotten a result? That's where my money is on for your bug.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have updated my question and ran the debugger I am getting this error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Are you familiar with debugging NPE's? You need to inspect the stacktrace, find the line causing the exception, find the variable on that line that is null, and then trace back into your code to see why it is null. You will run into these time and time again, so being familiar with them and how to handle them will be important. I again suspect that it may be null due to your Strings not behaving as you think they should be behaving. Again, a small compilable program would help us **immensely**. I can't stress this point enough.

Comment: It seems that somewhere inside your logic there's an immense flaw. Nailing down that error is hindered by the fact that your code makes excessive use of magic numbers (like 75) and is not followable. You don't even know what route the code takes. I get the feeling that your success isn't set to true, because whatever and your else branch doesn't restore the original chess-piece

Comment: Even with a 50 pt bounty, you're not seeing any new or better answers yet which suggests that this question still might benefit from more information including (and yes, I know I'm beating on a dead horse here), a minimal code example program. And yes, creating this does require effort, but others and I have been in your shoes before, and we've found that it has been effort well worth expending. Regardless, best of luck on your project and its completion. I sincerely hope that you get it to work well.

Comment: You must make a clear separation of business rules, AND event handling. There's a difference of what constitutes a legal move AND allowing the move. For example, a pawn can move two squares forward on the opening, or one square (as long as that square is not occupied).  HOWEVER, if that moves causes the king to be put in check, the "legal" move is not allowed. The point is that you need a rules engine outlining all of these scenarios, but your event handler should only do that, HANDLE THE EVENT (not enforcing business rules.) That will make your code simpler to follow (among other things).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've looked through some of your code, again there's too much for me to go through in its entirety, but please let me give you some suggestions.

This is brittle/dangerous code:

```
    JLabel awaitingPiece = (JLabel) c1;
    String tmp1 = awaitingPiece.getIcon().toString();
    if (((tmp1.contains("White")))) {
```

You're using an object's `toString()` representation as part of your code logic which is something you should never do. You're also doing String manipulations on the String returned, and again using the returned String for code logic,

```
    Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
    String tmp = chessPiece.getIcon().toString();
    String pieceName = tmp.substring(0, (tmp.length() - 4));
    Boolean validMove = false;
```

again something that is dangerous to do.

Instead, you could get the Icon and compare for Icon equality via the `equals(...)` method. Even better though is to get your logic out of your GUI and into the Model section of your program. If you can fully separate concerns, you'll stand a much better chance of having smaller units of code that are much easier to debug for both you **and for us**.

Otherwise, to get a better more complete answer, you're still going to want to first work to **isolate the error**, and for that, I still recommend that you use an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

---

Also I see that you're checking if an Icon is named "WhitePawn"

```
    chessPiece.setVisible(false);
    Boolean success = false;
    Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
    String tmp = chessPiece.getIcon().toString();
    String pieceName = tmp.substring(0, (tmp.length() - 4));
    Boolean validMove = false;

    //Pawn Moves
    //White Pawn
    if (pieceName.equals("WhitePawn")) {
```

When in actuality I'll bet that it's named something quite differently. Since your Strings are playing a key role in your program (too great a role, I fear) are you debugging your String values to see why the code doesn't work?

For instance, a few println's could do wonders:

```
    chessPiece.setVisible(false);
    Boolean success = false;
    Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
    String tmp = chessPiece.getIcon().toString();
    String pieceName = tmp.substring(0, (tmp.length() - 4));

    System.out.println("pieceName is: " + pieceName); // ******* Added ********

    Boolean validMove = false;
```

Myself, I'd not use Strings for this but rather would use enums, something you know will be stable and will be exactly what you assume it to be.

Comment: I have made the mod's you mention such as seeing what the actual name wa and even then linking that in I had no success the pieces still disappear once a release the mouse, I do know for a fact that thje problem is in the mouse release code, I just cant find it

Comment: @Jamiex304: Consider refactoring your code to both simplify it, and to break it down into separately testable units. Right now you've got at least one very large and complex class, and this makes it very hard to debug and to isolate errors. If I have time, I'll try to take more views of it this coming weekend. Consider posting a jar of the whole current app + images and other resources to a code share site.